# DateTime::format in German (day of the week)

Tags: php, datetime, format

I'd like to have a German output from `DateTime::format('D, d.m.Y H:i')` meaning that instead of 'Sun, ...' I want to get 'So, ...'. I set `setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE');` but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Rizier123 Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all set locale using [setlocale()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) function.

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'de_DE' );
```

convert timestamp into human readable date.

```
$local_date = date( 'l, d.m.Y', '1537551000' ); // 1537551000 timestamp
```

Format a local time/date according to locale settings using [strftime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function.

```
$de_date = strftime( '%A, %d.%m.%Y', strtotime( $local_date ) );
```

Comment: strftime() function has been deprecated since php8.1.0 - use date() instead.

Answer (score 0):

To quote [`the documentation for Datetime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

> This method does not use locales. All output is in English.

If you want to format a date in a different locale (in your case, German), you can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
date('D, d.m.Y H:i');
```

Comment: In this case I have to convert the DateTime object first (get the unix timestamp of it).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `strftime` in order to get localized output.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

```
// for english `date` is enough
echo date('D, d.m.Y H:i');
// --> Fri, 19.03.2021 17:22

// german localized string utf-8
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8');
echo strftime('%a, %d.%m.%Y %H:%I', time());
// --> Fr, 19.03.2021 17:05
```